# Can not query nodes but can see all the nodes and properties in the data browser

Tags: csv, import, neo4j

I have imported a few nodes with properties via the Cypher CSV import (command below) and the nodes seem to have loaded correctly as I can view them in the REST-API (the data browser). When I execute a `MATCH (n) RETURN n` query, all of the nodes are displayed in the Results pane, and when I click on one of the nodes the properties are displayed in the left pane of the browser (I would attach a screen shot showing what I am trying to refer to here which would make this issue A LOT more clear and easy to understand, but apparently us neophytes are prohibited from providing such useful information).

However, when I try to query any of the nodes directly, I get no rows returned. By "query the nodes directly" I am referring to querying with a `WHERE` condition where I ask for a specific property:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n:Type="Idea"
RETURN n
```

`Type` is one of the properties of the node. No rows are returned from the query. I can click on the node in the Stream pane to open the properties dialog, and I can see the Type property is clearly "Idea."

Am I missing something? The nodes and properties seemed to have loaded into the DB correctly, but I can't seem to query anything. Is "ID" a restricted term? Do I even need an "ID" property (i thought I read somewhere you shouldn't trust the auto-generated IDs as they aren't guaranteed to be unique over time)?

Import statement used to load the nodes is below:

```
$ auto-index name, ID
$ import-cypher  -i ProjectNodesCSV.csv -o ProjectOut.csv  CREATE (n:Project {ID:{ID},Name: {Name}, Type: {Type}, ProjectGroupName: {ProjectGroupName}, ProjectCategoryName: {ProjectCategoryName}, UnifierID: {UnifierID}, StartDate: {StartDate}, EndDate: {EndDate}, CapitalCosts: {CapitalCosts}, OandMCosts: {OandMCosts}}) RETURN ID(n) as ID, n.Name as Name
```

Comment: You have a typo in the `WHERE` clause, start with fixing that by changing `n:Type` to `n.Type`, since `Type` is a property and not a label.

Comment: Holy heck, I can't believe I missed that. I think I have been looking at this for too long! Changing the : to a . for the property does return the right node. Thanks for the assistance and sorry for troubling everyone.